# Translate model name by string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
model_name = self.class.name.demodulize.sub("Controller", "").singularize
message = t('activerecord.exceptions.not_found', model_name: model_name) 
render json: message, status: :not_found
```

And there is some YAML:

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    exceptions:
      not_found: "%{model_name} не найден"
```

As you can see I have Russian text in translation, but model name is still in English. How can I translate model name in Russian too? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try calling #human on model name? like self.class.model_name.human

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: пользователь
```

---

```
model_name = self.class.name.demodulize.sub("Controller", "").singularize
model_klass = model_name.constantize
message = t(
 'activerecord.exceptions.not_found', 
 model_name: model_klass.model_name.human
) 
render json: message, status: :not_found
```

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Note I google translated user - it is probably not the correct word.

Comment: Edited, should be `User.model_name.human` since self would refer to the controller.

Comment: I don't have model as AR class. I only have string as model name, i.e. 'User' just a string,

Comment: I see, you can get the class from a string by calling `"String".constantize`. Edited.

Comment: If your are doing this in a parent controller class I would get the model class in a private method which subclasses  can override if the controller name does not correspond to a model directly. (Like a SessionsController which actually deals with fetching users or authentication tokens).